# Using seq and math to manipulate the last octet in an ip address to create a file

Tags: bash, scripting, ip, math, seq

Ubuntu 16.04
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

We have to add ips to servers a few times a day. I find myself creating different variations of the same file according to the ip block.

```
#-- 100.100.100.160/29 - Sun 04/22/18 02-38-pm
#-- -----------------------------------------
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 100.100.100.160
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 100.100.100.161
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
    address 100.100.100.162
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
    address 100.100.100.163
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:4
iface eth0:4 inet static
    address 100.100.100.164
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:5
iface eth0:5 inet static
    address 100.100.100.165
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:6
iface eth0:6 inet static
    address 100.100.100.166
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:7
iface eth0:7 inet static
    address 99.100.100.167
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

So I figured to create a script to get me as close to that file as possible so I wrote a script and here is a portion of it ...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#-- bash add_ips.sh "eth0" "100.100.100.160" "255.255.255.255" "29"

wDir="/scripts/tools/ips"
ifaceFile="/etc/network/interfaces"
ipFile="${wDir}/ipFile.txt"
nic="${1}"
address="${2}"
netmask="${3}"
block="${4}"
timeStamp="$(date '+%a %D %I-%M-%P')"

if [ ! -n "$4" ]; then
   echo 'add_ips.sh nic address mask block ...';
   exit 1;
fi

#-- echo the address block on a header line
{
   echo "";
   echo "#-- IP Block ${address}/${block} - ${timeStamp}";
   echo "#-- ----------------------------------------------";
} > "$ipFile"

#-- If a 30/block
if [[ "$block" == "30" ]]; then
   start="0"
   end="3"
   for ipnum in $(seq "$start" "$end"); do
      {
         echo "auto ${nic}:${ipnum}";
         echo "iface ${nic}:${ipnum} inet static";
         echo -e "\t address ${address}";
         echo -e "\t netmask ${netmask}";
         echo "";
      } >> "$ipFile"
   done
```

The output was close to what I was looking for and the only thing left to do was change the last number of the ip address.

```
#-- 100.100.100.160/29 - Sun 04/22/18 02-38-pm
#-- -----------------------------------------
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 100.100.100.160
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 100.100.100.160
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
    address 100.100.100.160
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

How can I change the last octet of the ip address while adding the $seq value of the present loop on that line?

I tried this

```
#-- If a 30/block
if [[ "$block" == "30" ]]; then
   start="0"
   end="3"
   for ipnum in $(seq "$start" "$end"); do
      ipaddress=$(expr "$address" + "$ipnum")
      {
         echo "auto ${nic}:${ipnum}";
         echo "iface ${nic}:${ipnum} inet static";
         echo -e "\t address ${ipaddress}";
         echo -e "\t netmask ${netmask}";
         echo "";
      } >> "$ipFile"
   done
fi
```

The address is not an integer so it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the smallest change to make it work would be:

```
ipaddress=${address%.*}.$((${address##*.} + ipnum))
```

This sets `ipaddress` to:

- the `address` stripped of the trailing `dot` followed by anything (the last octet)
- a dot
- the mathematical expression `$(( ... ))` that adds:

  - the first octets of `address` (stripping as many characters as possible through the last dot it finds)
  - `ipnum`